# Kafka transforms.Filter to filter records based on Odd/Even numbers is not working with bitwise operator & and remainder % operator

Tags: java, filter, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, jsonpath

I have been trying to find a way to include a filter that discards the records with a particular value, in the Couchbase source connector. Lets say, I have the JSON: `{"key":10004, "name":"testt"}` and I want to discard all the records that have the key with all odd numbers . Is there a way to do that without having to use confluent platform?

I have installed confluent hub client and tried `filter.condition": "$[?(@.key&1 == 0)]"`, (bitwise operator) and also tried  `"$[?(@.key % 2 != 0)]"`. Seems like these both are not working. I also checked that JsonPath(https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) does not have this operators, does that mean these operatoes `% &` are not supported?

Comment: Please clarify what Filter transform you are using. Kafka Connect is not unique to Confluent Platform

Comment: I am trying to use something like this                                                "transforms.filterValue.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
"transforms.filterValue.filter.condition": "$[?(@.key&1 == 0)]",
"transforms.filterValue.filter.type": "include",

Comment: That Transform is part of this package, which can be added to any Kafka installation - https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/connect-transforms

Comment: Yeah I already did step by doing below                                                                               confluent-hub install confluentinc/connect-transforms:latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitwise [operations](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions) are not supported by the JSONPath library being used.

If you want to filter even/odds, use Kafka Streams or KSQL to create a new topic before writing to the database.

Comment: Thank you, I was planning on using streams as json path library was not supporting Bitwise and % operations. Thanks a lot for helping on this query

Answer (score 0):

As [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#functions) docs show, you can filter array elements with RegEx, using the `=~` operator.

So, JSONPath to filter

- odd numbers of an array: `[?(@ =~ /^\\d*[13579]$/)]`
- even numbers of an array: `[?(@ =~ /^\\d*[02468]$/)]`

(Used `\\d` instead of `\d` here as escape sequence.)

*PS: I was facing similar scenario while writing State Machine definitions in AWS Step Functions, and this worked for me.*